# Using a hash key to refer to an existing array

Tags: ruby

if I have the following arrays:

```
alice = ["phone", "telegraph"]
bob   = ["paper", "book" ]
carol = ["photograph", "painting"]
```

and this hash:

```
test_hash = { "alice" => "employee 1", "bob" => "employee 2", "carol" => "employee 3" }
```

how would I iterate through the hash and use the key value to refer back to the array so that I can pull, for example, the fact that alice has the phone?

Comment: I strongly recommend to avoid relying on variables' names. You can make another hashes, like  `person1 = {alice => ["phone", "something else"]}`, then collect all your persons into `persons` array and query that array. Again, don't rely on variable naming.

Comment: agree with @cdshines this schema smells bad.

Comment: Good advice. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a hash as below first:

```
hsh = {"alice" => ["phone", "telegraph"],
       "bob"   => ["paper", "book" ],
       "carol" => ["photograph", "painting"]}

test_hash = { "alice" => "employee 1", "bob" => "employee 2", "carol" => "employee 3" }

test_hash.each{|k,v| puts v if hsh.has_key?(k)}
# >> employee 1
# >> employee 2
# >> employee 3
```

or,

```
test_hash.each{|k,v| puts hsh[k] if hsh.has_key?(k)}
# >> phone
# >> telegraph
# >> paper
# >> book
# >> photograph
# >> painting
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the way to go. It's a case of "do it right in the first place".

Comment: @AltGrendel Good that you chose the right way, but your question was "how would I iterate through the hash and use the key value to refer back to the array", not "what's the best practice to implement the data structure". ;-p

Comment: True, and I appreciate that you folks both gave me the actual answer to the question and recommended that I keep with best practices before it caused issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended, but doable:

```
alice = ["phone", "telegraph"]
bob   = ["paper", "book" ]
carol = ["photograph", "painting"]

test_hash = { "alice" => "employee 1", "bob" => "employee 2", "carol" => "employee 3" }

test_hash.keys.each {|k| puts "#{k} has phone." if eval(k).include? 'phone'}
```